# how to make if else condition in react

Tags: html, reactjs

how to make if else condition dynamic on the basis of click button i tried but not work.

i tried this way condition but not work  suppose like i want to click buton which is Español then i want print language spanish like other i want to click buton which is 标准粤语then i want print language cantonese like i want if else condition
how can we do that .

```
        const settings = {language: {summaryLanguage}}
        const language = settings.language;
        if(foreignLanguageMap[language] === text){
            console.log('text', {text},{language});
        }



const summaryLanguage = {
    english: 'english',
    spanish: 'spanish',
    vietnamese: 'vietnamese',
    tagalog: 'tagalog',
    cantonese: 'cantonese',
    mandarin: 'mandarin'
};

 const foreignLanguageMap = {
    english: 'English',
    spanish: 'Español',
    vietnamese: 'Tiếng Việt',
    tagalog: 'Tagalog',
    cantonese: '标准粤语',
    mandarin: '普通話'
};
```

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[check it Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-rendering-ehez36)

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const enum enumButtonTypes {
  ESPANOL = "Español",
  CANTONESE = "标准粤语"
}
const buttons = [enumButtonTypes.ESPANOL, enumButtonTypes.CANTONESE];
export default function App() {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState<enumButtonTypes | string>("");
  const renderButton = useCallback(() => {
    switch (current) {
      case enumButtonTypes.ESPANOL:
        return <div>{enumButtonTypes.ESPANOL}</div>;
        break;
      case enumButtonTypes.CANTONESE:
        return <div>{enumButtonTypes.CANTONESE}</div>;
        break;
      default:
        return <div>default</div>;
        break;
    }
  }, [current]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {buttons.map((button) => (
        <button onClick={() => setCurrent(button)}>{button}</button>
      ))}
      <div>{renderButton()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```